# Can a WebSocket server coexist with a HTTP Apache server in the same public port (80), but locally in different address?

Tags: http, websocket, portforwarding

Firstly, I have a HTTP Server with Apache 2.4 in Windows working perfectly fine with a simple website, 
so I forwarded external port 80 to the local port 80 of my Windows machine in my router.

And I want to run a WebSocket server on my Raspberry PI for doing crazy things with python, and I tried to forward the external port 80 also to the local port 80 of the Raspberry.
And I tried to connect to the python WebSocket server running on my Raspberry, with a JS script in a website, and it says: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Then I noted that my simple website in my Apache server was not loading correctly (very slowly), the majority of the time it didn't load it at all, chrome said: Connection refused. Then I undone the Raspberry port rule and then it was loading completely fine.

So, is that the two mentioned protocols can't coexist (probably they do)? or its just a problem with port forwarding?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the routing. When you use port forwarding in your router, it's happening on the transport layer (4) of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Here a socket is defined by 3 things: protocol, address, port. Which in this case is `tcp:<Your-IP-Address>:80`. You can only forward that to one location. HTTP and WebSocket protocols are on higher layers and are not visible to the router, they are passed along only as data.

You will need to use a different port number for one of them, or use a reverse proxy server, such as HAProxy or nginx, that can process the higher level protocols and router accordingly.